# How to communicate with a local API with AngularDart

Tags: django, cors, django-rest-framework, dart, django-cors-headers

I can communicate in AngularDart with a public API but not with my local API.

```
 String _url = 'localhost:8000/kanji_detail/1000/?format=json';
 String _url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
```

I can get the JSON info from both urls in my browser, but can only connect in AngularDart with the second url. I tried the http methods and client instead of the BrowserClient with no effect, and the code only works when using the BrowserClient and a public API.

Here is the code:

```
import "dart:async";
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
//import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';


@Component (
  selector: "test",
  template: """
    <button (click)="change_info()">{{info}}</button>
    """,
)
class Test {
  BrowserClient client = new BrowserClient();
  //var client = new http.Client();
  String info = "default info";
  String _url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/kanji_detail/1000/?format=json';
  //String _url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";

  Future get_info() async {
    var response = await client.get(_url);
    info = JSON.decode(response.body);
    //return JSON.decode(response.body);
  }

  change_info() {
    get_info();
  }

}
```

Comment: I assume you get an error message in the browser console. This error message would be helpful. I also assume the cause is that the local server doesn't return the CORS headers the browser expects. The browser expects some headers in the response to a request when the domain or port is different then where the code making the request was loaded from. Search for CORS to learn more (very frequently asked topic)

Comment: Hey thanks for the hint, the server not returning the CORS header was the problem, I solved it by configuring the server. The console wasn't showing any errors btw.

Comment: Interesting, the bowser definitely should show errors if a request fails. Glad to hear you could make it work anyway.

Comment: Consider self-answering the question if you found a solution on your own; this will help other people who stumble on this question see that there is a solution available.

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't about Angular Dart but it was on the server configuration, Django in my case. I solved it by enabling CORS headers configuration and whitelisting there my localhost. In Django I:

1. Installed django-cors-header module in the terminal.

   pip install django-cors-headers
2. Added the module to the installed apps list.

   INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ...
   'corsheaders',
   ...
   )
3. Added the middleware class to the configuration

   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   ...
   'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
   ...
   )
4. And whitelisting localhost.

   CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
   'localhost:8080',
   '127.0.0.1:8080'
   )